# Finding the amount of steps between values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I have a database table with the following content:

| person1_id | person2_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 4 |
| 2 | 3 |

(this table continues for about 60k rows with pairs of people, the pairs can occur multiple times and aren't set in stone, so person 1 can also be paired with person 3)

I need to know the amount of steps a person is away from another, so for example how many steps away is 1 from 4 it would take 3 steps (1->2->3->4).

As an output I'd expect something alike:

| person1_id | person2_id | steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

From what I found it should be possible using [recursive queries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html), but I have no idea how to approach the problem

Comment: Seems feasible, though your post is unclear and the presented sample rows are too few. This problem requires more sample inputs, expected output table and possibly non-consecutive values, more information regarding those specific numbers (if non-consecutiveness is allowed in your original data), what they mean in the context you're working in.

Comment: Hey @lemon, thanks for the response, I've updated the question in the hopes it's more clear now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a recursive query, you can identify two steps:

- Base Step: contains existing rows, according to which we want to recur on.
- Recursive Step: contains new rows, generated from the Base Step at timestep 0, and from the both Base and Recursive Step at timesteps 1+.

---

**"*Base*" Step**

First we want to select the relevant rows to build our Base Step. For this one, I'm assuming you don't want rows like "*(2, 4, 2)*" and "*(3, 4, 1)*", so basically you always want "*person1_id*" to not appear among "*person2_id*" values.

```
SELECT person1_id FROM tab 
EXCEPT
SELECT person2_id FROM tab
```

| person1_id |
| --- |
| 1 |

This will give us just the "*person1_id*", hence in order to get back the full rows which have these ids, you can do a `JOIN` operation as follows:

```
SELECT tab.person1_id, tab.person2_id, 1 AS steps
FROM       tab 
INNER JOIN (SELECT person1_id FROM tab 
            EXCEPT
            SELECT person2_id FROM tab) p1_never_p2
        ON tab.person1_id = p1_never_p2.person1_id
```

| person1_id | person2_id | steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 1 |

Note that "*steps*" field will be always initialized to 1 here, as long as we are in Base Step (the distance between any row belonging to the original table between "*person1_id*" and "*person2_id*" is always 1).

---

**"*Recursive*" Step**

In this step we want to match the current table's "*person2_id*" with the original table's "*person1_id*", while keeping current table's "*person1_id*" and original table's "*person2_id*" (if I have 1-2 in the current and 2-3 in the original, I want to keep 1-3 because both rows match on the 2). The current output will be kept by the recursive query, and that's what we find in the `JOIN` with the original table.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT tab.person1_id, tab.person2_id, 1 AS steps
    FROM       tab 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT person1_id FROM tab 
                EXCEPT
                SELECT person2_id FROM tab) p1_never_p2
            ON tab.person1_id = p1_never_p2.person1_id

    UNION ALL

    SELECT cte.person1_id, tab.person2_id, cte.steps + 1 AS steps
    FROM       cte
    INNER JOIN tab
            ON cte.person2_id = tab.person1_id
)
```

Note that this subquery is called "*cte*", though it is called inside, within the FROM clause, to apply the `INNER JOIN`. Also note that we increment the steps value that we keep updating inside "*cte*".

| person1_id | person2_id | steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 3 | 2 |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

Basically what you see here is the base step (row 1) and every recursive step (rows 2 and 3). We have all rows from both steps because of the `UNION ALL` operation.

---

Since we want only the combinations with the highest amount of step for each "*person1_id*" value, we can use the `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` constraint as follows:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
    SELECT tab.person1_id, tab.person2_id, 1 AS steps
    FROM       tab 
    INNER JOIN (SELECT person1_id FROM tab 
                EXCEPT
                SELECT person2_id FROM tab) p1_never_p2
            ON tab.person1_id = p1_never_p2.person1_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT cte.person1_id, tab.person2_id, cte.steps + 1 AS steps
    FROM       cte
    INNER JOIN tab
            ON cte.person2_id = tab.person1_id
)
SELECT * 
FROM cte
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY person1_id ORDER BY steps DESC)
FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES
```

The `ROW_NUMBER` window function will generate the value 1 for each "*person1_id*" biggest amount of steps, then the `FETCH FIRST ROWS WITH TIES` will keep the rows whose `ROW_NUMBER` is equal to 1, tied.

| person1_id | person2_id | steps |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 |

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ga5DzGxQwo4BNTMiEw4wk9/0).